# Android Eclipse - Switching consecutive Activities

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm new to programming in Eclipse and we were tasked to create a "minigame" just by using switching activities.

My idea was a "Maze game" where there would be buttons for directions and pressing them would switch to another activity with another set of buttons until the player either finds a dead end or the exit.

My problem is that at the 3rd level of switching, the buttons are unable to switch activities anymore.

(e.g. MainActivity ("PLAY") -> MainActivity2("Forward/Left/Right") -> Forward1("Left/Right") -> Both Left and Right cease to function at this point)

MainActivity.java

```
package ct.android.mazerunner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnPlay;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);

        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

}
}
```

MainActivity2.java

```
package ct.android.mazerunner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

    Button buttonF;
    Button buttonL;
    Button buttonR;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        buttonF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);

        buttonF.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Forward1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        buttonL = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLeft);

        buttonL.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DeadEnd.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        buttonR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRight);

        buttonR.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Right1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

}
}
```

Forward1.java

```
package ct.android.mazerunner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Forward1 extends Activity {

    Button buttonR1;
    Button buttonL1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.forward1);
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        buttonR1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRight2);

        buttonR1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DeadEnd.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        buttonL1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLeft2);

        buttonL1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Forward1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ct.android.mazerunner"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="MainActivity2"></activity>
        <activity android:name="Forward1"></activity>
        <activity android:name="Right1"></activity>
        <activity android:name="DeadEnd"></activity>
        <activity android:name="Left2"></activity>
        <activity android:name="Escape"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

There are other activities which I haven't added the codes to keep this shorter. There's not much of a difference from one activity to another anyways.

Comment: I think you just forgot to call the addListenerOnButton() method in your Forward1 onCreate method...

Comment: Well that did it, facepalm to myself I guess. Thanks!